# Time stamp conversion while inserting data to bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sqlalchemy, google-developers-console, pybigquery

i'm trying to run a insert query at bigquery to insert row, but failing due to timestamp conversion issue, can any one help out here

**Bigquery table Schema:**

fieldname type
status  STRING  NULLABLE
created_on  TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE
updated_on  TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE
deleted_on  TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE
created_by  STRING  NULLABLE
deleted_by  STRING  NULLABLE
updated_by  STRING  NULLABLE
is_deleted  BOOLEAN NULLABLE
id  INTEGER NULLABLE
msl_code    STRING  NULLABLE
first_name  STRING  NULLABLE
last_name   STRING  NULLABLE
speciality  STRING  NULLABLE
phone_number    STRING  NULLABLE
clinic_name STRING  NULLABLE
address STRING  NULLABLE
pincode INTEGER NULLABLE
mini_region STRING  NULLABLE
lat NUMERIC NULLABLE
lng NUMERIC NULLABLE
doctor_unique_id    STRING  NULLABLE

**query used:**

INSERT INTO
`doctors` (status,
created_on,
updated_on,
deleted_on,
created_by,
deleted_by,
updated_by,
is_deleted,
id,
msl_code,
first_name,
last_name,
speciality,
phone_number,
clinic_name,
address,
pincode,
mini_region,
lat,
lng,
doctor_unique_id)
VALUES
('ACTIVE','2022-07-09T06:51:45','2022-07-09T06:51:45','','b52e690b-e2c3-4a5e-9fec-4301d0586bd8','','','','4','01128989','A','Goplarao','Cardiologist','55656565656','Chitara Clinic','Shop No.12 Municipal Shopping Complex,Seethammadha','530022','Visaerekhapatnam','17.7432938','83.31475689999999','01128989_530022_Chitara_Clinic');

Erorr Obtained: Could not cast literal "" to type TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 1):

Your `deleted_on` value should not be `''` as that is not a valid TIMESTAMP.

If you want it to become `NULL` in your table, try leaving it blank, as shown below:

```
INSERT INTO doctors 
(status, created_on, updated_on, deleted_on, created_by, deleted_by,
updated_by, is_deleted, id, msl_code, first_name, last_name, speciality, 
phone_number, clinic_name, address, pincode, mini_region, lat, lng, 
doctor_unique_id) 

VALUES ('ACTIVE','2022-07-09T06:51:45','2022-07-09T06:51:45',,'b52e690b-e2c3-4a5e-9fec-4301d0586bd8','','','','4','01128989','A','Goplarao','Cardiologist','55656565656','Chitara Clinic','Shop No.12 Municipal Shopping Complex,Seethammadha','530022','Visaerekhapatnam','17.7432938','83.31475689999999','01128989_530022_Chitara_Clinic');
```

Comment: try leaving it blank - not worked,  using  'null' worked